# Moving from Docker Compose to Kubernetes, storing configuration on persistent volumes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, azure-aks

I am new to Kubernetes, but I have been using Docker and Docker Compose for a long time.  I am trying to find more information about how Kubernetes handles shared/read only config files compared to Docker Compose.

In my `docker-compose.yaml` file I am sharing specific config files to my containers using bind mounts, similar to this:

```
  ...
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.3.2
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    networks: 
      mycoolapp:
        aliases: 
          - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    volumes:
      - elasticdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
   ...
```

I have been reading up on Persistent Volumes and I believe this is what I need, however, my understanding still isn't 100% clear on a few issues.

1. I'm using `azureFile` for my volume type, and I have copied my configs into the file share.  How do I mount a sub folder of the file share into my container?  `mountPath` only appears in `volumeMounts`, and I can't find where the corresponding location within the volume are.
2. How do I share just a single file?
3. How do I make the single file that I shared above read only?

Comment: Kubernetes has a dedicated [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) object that's good for injecting config files and environment settings.  I wouldn't try to use a PersistentVolume here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubernetes ConfigMap object will come handy here.

> A ConfigMap is an API object used to store non-confidential data in key-value pairs.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: elastic-demo
data:
  # property-like keys; each key maps to a simple value; available as env var
  properties_file_name: "database.properties"

  # file-like keys
  database.properties: |
    data1=value1
    data2=value2
```

You can mount the above ConfigMap in volume in read only mode.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: elasticsearch
    volumeMounts:
    - name: elastic-volume
      mountPath: "/etc/foo"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: elastic-volume
    configMap:
      name: elastic-demo
```

Comment: For a `properties_file_name`, can I add any file type or does it have to be string literals/key-value pairs?  Can it be a .json file, or even a .bin file?  Also, if I have a folder structure with 100s of files, is there a way to import everything and maintain the file paths?

Comment: 'properties_file_name'  is a key value pair here. You can use any key value pair and file can be .json/.bin or any type.

Comment: What about folders?  Is there a way to automatically import 100s of files into a configMap?  Or should I just hand jam them all?

Comment: There is no option to add folder or directory in ConfigMap now. You have to jam them all individually in ConfigMap.

Comment: Should I include each file in an individual configmap? or should I include each folder's worth of files in an individual configmap?  Thank you for the info so far! I think this what I'm looking for

Comment: It is totally up to you. But my recommendation is to use less configmap as you have to mount them into volumes. If you use so many configmap objects then you have to mount them all in volumes. This will make your manifest yaml file messy.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pulak said it correctly you can use configmap. I saw you want to import a folder containing 100s of files into a configmap. What I think is, you can do this in another way. That is using zip/jar file as ConfigMap support binary file, so after mounting it can be unzipped into your desired path inside the container.

For example you have below structure in the folder:

```
.
├── test1.html
├── test2.css
├── test3.xml
└── testN.html
```

Now you can make them jar/zip and can create a configmap by `kubectl create configmap example --from-file=./`

Another thing is configmap size (in terms of MiB) should not be large. So, if you really have lot of things than can use kubernetes typical volumes.